# Using named capture groups inside Ruby gsub blocks (regex)

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I'm trying to use a named capture group inside a block in Ruby. `$1` still works, but I'd like to reference it using the name I gave.

```
"foo /(bar)".gsub(/(?<my_word> \(.*?\) )/x) do |match|
  puts "$1 = #{$1} and $my_word = #{$my_word}"
end
```

Expected:`$1 = (bar) and $my_word = (bar)`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You are looking for

```
"foo /(bar)".gsub(/(?<my_word> \(.*?\) )/x) do |match|
  puts "$1 = #{$1} and $my_word = #{$~[:my_word]}"
end
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I've never seen anything like that syntax before.

Comment: Can you give me a good Regex tutorial link? I know `zero` about `regex`. :(

Comment: Is there a reason you need the `?` in `\(.*?\)`? In my understanding, that's saying "zero or more of any character, zero or more times," which seems the same as just "zero or more of any character," i.e. `\(.*\)`

Comment: @acobster the interrogation point `?` is a modifier of the star: it makes it a non-greedy operator, so it will end on the first occurrence of the following expression. But I just copied paste the OP's code so you should ask him :)

Comment: @acobster It's been a while since I wrote this, but I believe it was to keep it from capturing stuff in parentheses following the first pair. i.e., the 'bar' in `(foo)(bar)`. If it was greedy, it would start at the far left and capture everything up to the last parentheses.

Comment: the `$~` is equivalent to `Regexp.last_match`